# Change markers type in chart

Tags: plotting

How can I get the markers types to be different (red color--round, blue color---square, orange color---star, black color---triangle).

```
dd = 0.832606; ee = -1.87416; ff = 0.396505;ContourPlot[dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2, {i, -10, 10}, {l, -10, 10}], Contours -> {0}, ContourShading -> None,Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{0.4, 0}], Blue,Point[{0.1, 0}], Orange, Point[{0.3, 0}], Black,Point[{0.2, 0}]}]
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

dd = 0.832606;
ee = -1.87416;
ff = 0.396505;
```

Use [`ListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) to add [`PlotMarkers`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html)

```
Show[
 ContourPlot[
  dd i^2 + ee i l + ff l^2 - 0.55^2,
  {i, -1, 1}, {l, -1, 1},
  Contours -> {0},
  ContourShading -> None],
 ListPlot[List /@ {{0.1, 0}, {0.2, 0}, {0.3, 0}, {0.4, 0}},
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Black, Orange, Red},
  PlotMarkers -> ({#, 20} & /@ {"■", "▲", "★", "●"})]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for helping